# free heap esp32, string-formatter

Tags: c++, arduino, string-formatting, heap-memory, esp32

I'm using the function **storePrintf** for string formatting (googled it) - it works fine, but on 3d or 4th day I see the next error:

`[E][ssl_client.cpp:33] _handle_error(): [start_ssl_client():199]: (-17040) RSA - The public key operation failed : BIGNUM - Memory allocation failed`

simplified code shows the order of functions calls

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}
char *buf ;
char *storePrintf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
  va_list arg;
  va_start(arg, fmt);
  size_t sz = snprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, arg);
  buf = (char *)malloc(sz + 1);
  vsprintf(buf, fmt, arg);
  va_end(arg);
  return buf;
}

void loop() {
  String s = storePrintf("==========================: ml = %.2f, val = %d\n", 0.12, 2);
   Serial.println("s = " + s);
   free(buf);  
  delay(2000);
}
// this works well, but if code has a lot of calls to storePrintf with free(buf) gets error
```

I suppose that Memory allocation failed due to the never call `free(buf);` after allocation memory for **buf**.
when I try to call `free(buf);` directly after calling `storePrintf(..)` in some moment appears another error:

`CORRUPT HEAP: Bad tail at 0x3ffdb993. Expected 0xbaad5678 got 0xbaad5600 assertion "head != NULL" failed`

Help please to fix this issue,

Comment: `snprintf` and `vsprintf` don't do the same thing so the size to be allocation may be incorrect.  Try replacing the call to `snprintf` with `vsnprintf`.

Comment: `snprintf` doesn't take `va_list`, but rather "normal" `prinft` arguments. Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of passing an argument whose type doesn't match the format specifier. You are likely looking for `vsnprintf`

Comment: In addition, `va_list` is single-pass, it's invalid to reuse it. Either call `va_start` again, or use `va_copy` to clone it before first use.

Comment: By the way, you only need to call `free()` or `delete` after you called `malloc()` or `new`. `CORRUPT HEAP` mean that the memory which is pointed by the pointer is not allocated on the heap. Whenever you assign a pointer, such as `char*`, without calling `malloc()` or `new`, it is stored on the stack, not on the heap. So you don't need to call `free()` or `delete`.